# syntax error in SQL statement (create table if not exists)

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, syntax

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ax_storage 
(PID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 PRIMARY KEY(PID), 
 Playername VARCHAR(32), 
 Time INT(10), Type INT(6), 
 World VARCHAR(32);
```

What is wrong with this SQL statement?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: you need a last ) before ;

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing to close a paranthesis at the end of the query

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ax_storage 
(
    PID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    PRIMARY KEY(PID), Playername VARCHAR(32), 
    Time INT(10), 
    Type INT(6), 
    World VARCHAR(32)
);  -- <- you were missing this one
```

Answer (score 2):

you forgot `)` in the end of query

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ax_storage (PID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(PID), Playername VARCHAR(32), Time INT(10), Type INT(6), World VARCHAR(32));
```